# Depth-first search returning wrong value

Tags: php, depth-first-search

```
class Graph 
{
    protected $_len = 0;
    protected $_g = array();
    protected $_visited = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_g = array(
            array(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0),
            array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0),
            array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0),
            array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ,0),
            array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,1),
            array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,1),
            array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0),
        );

        $this->_len = count($this->_g);

        $this->_initVisited();
    }

    protected function _initVisited()
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->_len; $i++) {
            $this->_visited[$i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public function depthFirst($vertex)
    {
        $this->_visited[$vertex] = 1;
        echo $vertex . "\n";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->_len; $i++) {
            if ($this->_g[$vertex][$i] == 1 && !$this->_visited[$i]) {
                $this->depthFirst($i);
            }
        }
    }
}

$g = new Graph();
$g->depthFirst(1);
```

I want to find the topological order of this graph
The output is `1 0 3 4 6 5`. It is missing the number `2`. In this case, there are two starting points in graph. 
point `(1,0)` and point `(2,0)`

How can I solve the problem?